# Wait function completed before render in React Native

Tags: react-native, rendering, react-context

I'm facing with problem,
I'm use context for socket io.
In App.js:

```
let loginInfo;
let socket = null;

// Listening notification on background or quit
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  // Init socket,
  // Start call
});

// Read AsyncStorage
const getLoginData = async () => {
  loginInfo = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage._retrieveData('loginInfo'));
  if (loginInfo && loginInfo?.isJoinedRoom) {
    socket = io(loginInfo.url, {timeout: 10000, reconnection: false});
    
    // Here print later
    console.log('socket in appjs: ', socket); // 1 -> Socket in here assigned
  }
};
getLoginData();

const App = () => {
  // here print first
  console.log('Socket in appjs 2', socket); // 2 -> Socket in here is null
  return (
    <>
      <SocketProvider value={socket}>
        <MainContainer />
      </SocketProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm want to wait function getLoginData is completed before rendering App. SocketProvider with value alway null.

Can you show me how to wait a function completed before rendering, thank.

I try to set another variable in getLoginData `let completed = false`
and use in App.js but not work :

```
{completed ? (
        <SocketProvider value={socket}>
          <MainContainer />
        </SocketProvider>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
```

Comment: Take a look at how to implement conditionally rendering screens: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/.

Answer (score 0):

The `completed` won't work because you are using `completed = false` in getLoginData as a normal variable... You'll have to use it as a state, i.e.

```
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);
```

And then in the getLoginData function, once you are done, set the state to `true`

And use it just like you used it above.

Comment: I want to call it outside of the body of a function component. So when try to call hook outside function component, a error throw: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Comment: React doesn't play well with variables outside of components generally, particularly when it comes to state and rendering. I'd recommend you to move the function inside the component.